# How to efficiently insert large amount of data in mysql using spring data jpa?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I used the following Code to insert large amount of data in database.

**Problem**

1)Is there any way I can optimize the insert query so that the query can be applied like

insert into x values(id,description,location),(id,description,location) ....

where id,description and location can be fetched dynamically

2)Though I tried using @Query Annotation but was unable to apply  insert query and fetch dynamic input into the above query

> Can anyone guide me how to solve this problem or if any better approach that exist.Thankx in advance.

**Solution I Implemented**

1)In this example I was not able to implement insert query and I tried different insert way to insert.

**Item Entity**

```
Entity
@Table(name = "Item")
public class Item {

private static AtomicLong lastId = new AtomicLong();
@Id
private Long id=lastId.incrementAndGet();

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "location")
private String location;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

**BulkInsert EndPoint**

```
@PostMapping("/bulkInsert")
ApiResponse<List<Item>> post() {
    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setDescription("JalajDesc" + i);
        item.setLocation("Jalaj Location" + i);
        itemList.add(item);
}
return ApiResponse.success().object(bulkImporterRepository1.bulkSave(itemList));
}
```

**BulkImporterRepository1**

```
@Repository
public  class BulkImporterRepository1 extends SimpleJpaRepository<Item, Long> {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}")
private int batchSize;

public BulkImporterRepository1(EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(Item.class, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}


@Transactional
public <T extends Item> List<Item> bulkSave(List<Item> entities) {
    final List<Item> savedEntities = new ArrayList<Item>(entities.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (Item t : entities) {
        savedEntities.add(persistOrMerge(t));
        i++;
        if (i % batchSize == 0) {
            // Flush a batch of inserts and release memory.
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }
    }
    return savedEntities;
}
```

**Logs of Hibernate**

```
2018-03-04 18:20:58.839 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL
: select item0_.id as id1_0_0_,  item0_.description as descript2_0_0_, item0_.location as location3_0_0_ from item item0_ where item0_.id=?
2018-03-04 18:20:58.839 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select item0_.id as id1_0_0_, item0_.description as descript2_0_0_, item0_.location as location3_0_0_ from item item0_ where item0_.id=?
2018-03-04 18:20:58.839 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select item0_.id as id1_0_0_, item0_.description as descript2_0_0_, item0_.location as location3_0_0_ from item item0_ where item0_.id=?
2018-03-04 18:20:58.839 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select item0_.id as id1_0_0_, item0_.description as descript2_0_0_, item0_.location as location3_0_0_ from item item0_ where item0_.id=?
2018-03-04 18:20:58.839 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select item0_.id as id1_0_0_, item0_.description as descript2_0_0_, item0_.location as location3_0_0_ from item item0_ where item0_.id=?
2018-03-04 18:20:58.840 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into item (description, location, id) values (?, ?, ?)
2018-03-04 18:20:58.840 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into item (description, location, id) values (?, ?, ?)
2018-03-04 18:20:58.840 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into item (description, location, id) values (?, ?, ?)
2018-03-04 18:20:58.840 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into item (description, location, id) values (?, ?, ?)
2018-03-04 18:20:58.840 DEBUG 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into item (description, location, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

**Session Metrics**

```
2018-03-04 18:20:58.918  INFO 10703 --- [nio-6005-exec-1] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
447529 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
72032184 nanoseconds spent preparing 2040 JDBC statements;
241834982 nanoseconds spent executing 2000 JDBC statements;
185823486 nanoseconds spent executing 40 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
307745133 nanoseconds spent executing 40 flushes (flushing a total of 2000 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

**Application.propeeties **

Hibernate

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Connection

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=x
spring.datasource.password=x
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.name=test
```

Pool

```
spring.datasource.initial-size=10
spring.datasource.max-active=50
spring.datasource.min-idle=5
spring.datasource.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1;
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=60000
spring.datasource.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=300000

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```